# How to respond to UDP Multicast from UDPClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, udp, multicast

I want to preface this by saying my understanding of UDP Broadcasting and Multicasting is very limited. This is my first project working on this.

I have a C# desktop client running on a machine and a Windows phone 7 app.
The WP7 app is supposed to send a UDP broadcast over the network and the desktop client is supposed to listen for a UDP Multicast and respond accordingly. This is just meant for simple machine discovery over the network to find machines running the desktop client.

C# Desktop Client Code

```
    public class ConnectionListener
{
    private const int UDP_PORT = 54322;
    private static readonly IPAddress MULTICAST_GROUP_ADDRESS = IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.1");

    private UdpClient _listener;

    public ConnectionListener()
    {
        _listener = new UdpClient(UDP_PORT, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        _listener.EnableBroadcast = true;
        _listener.JoinMulticastGroup(MULTICAST_GROUP_ADDRESS);

        _listener.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback, null);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        IPEndPoint receiveEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, UDP_PORT);
        byte[] receivedBytes = _listener.EndReceive(result, ref receiveEndpoint);

        byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WPF Response");
        _listener.BeginSend(response, response.Length, receiveEndpoint, SendCallback, null);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        int sendCount = _listener.EndSend(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent Count is: " + sendCount);
    }
}
```

The WP7 Server code:

```
    public class MachineDetector
{
    public const int UDP_PORT = 54322;
    private const string MULTICAST_GROUP_ADDRESS = "224.0.0.1";

    UdpAnySourceMulticastClient _client = null;
    bool _joined = false;

    private byte[] _receiveBuffer;
    private const int MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE = 512;

    public MachineDetector()
    {
        _client = new UdpAnySourceMulticastClient(IPAddress.Parse(MULTICAST_GROUP_ADDRESS), UDP_PORT);
        _receiveBuffer = new byte[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];

        _client.BeginJoinGroup(
            result =>
            {
                _client.EndJoinGroup(result);
                _client.MulticastLoopback = false;
                SendRequest();
            }, null);
    }

    private void SendRequest()
    {
        byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WP7 Multicast");

        _client.BeginSendToGroup(requestData, 0, requestData.Length,
            result =>
            {
                _client.EndSendToGroup(result);
                Receive();
            }, null);
    }

    private void Receive()
    {
        Array.Clear(_receiveBuffer, 0, _receiveBuffer.Length);
        _client.BeginReceiveFromGroup(_receiveBuffer, 0, _receiveBuffer.Length,
            result =>
            {
                IPEndPoint source;

                _client.EndReceiveFromGroup(result, out source);

                string dataReceived = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_receiveBuffer, 0, _receiveBuffer.Length);

                string message = String.Format("[{0}]: {1}", source.Address.ToString(), dataReceived);
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                Receive();
            }, null);
    }
}
```

I am able to receive data with the desktop client, but the WP7 app doesn't seem able to receive the response. I've been banging my head on this for a while now and don't know where else to look. Any help would be great.

So, any suggestions why the WP7 app isn't receiving a response?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `ConnectionListener:ReceiveCallback` in `C# Desktop Client`.

```
    _listener.BeginSend(response, response.Length,
         receiveEndpoint, SendCallback, null);
```

Instead call

```
    _listener.BeginSend(response, response.Length,
        SendCallback, null);
```

This will cause the message to be sent to the multicast address. For further help with this refer to [How to: Send and Receive Data in a Multicast Group for Windows Phone.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286407.aspx)

Comment: @AlRodriguez Your right. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx13cwba.aspx) says about `BeginSend` that `destination is to be specified earlier by a call to Connect`. But it also says `Do not call the Connect method if you intend to receive multicasted datagrams.`

Answer (score 0):

WP7 **needs** to multicast to the network in order to efficiently reach all desktop clients in one sweep. For the client response, the only intended destination is WP7. As such, a multicast has no real advantage here (as the desktop clients tuned into the multicast will effectively be ignoring it).

Instead, you could use `receiveEndpoint` populated by the call to `EndReceive` in `ConnectionListener:ReceiveCallback` to send a `unicast` response to the WP7 server. This is recommended `consideration` for creating multicast applications at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286407.aspx#BKMK_OTHER).

This way WP7 no longer needs to `join` the multicast group for incoming multicast and the desktop client needn't `send` a multicast to respond.